# What could be the CSS Selector for the following HTML source

Tags: css, selenium-webdriver

```
<button id="createDropdown" class="btn-create" tabindex="7">
<ul id="createDropdownUl" class="dropdown-create" style="display: block">
<li tabindex="8">
<button>BOOK MASTER SERVICE </button>
</li>
<li tabindex="9">
<button> CREATE SCHEDULE</button>
</li>
</ul>
</div>
```

I want to select the Button with text "CREATE SCHEDULE". The xpath for the expression is;

```
//*[@id='createDropdownUl']/li[2]/button
```

I have tried the following code. ;

```
 WebElement menuitem=driver.findElement(By.cssSelector("ul#createDropdownUl>li>button"));
```

But it selects Both buttons I  only want to select the second button "CREATE SCHEDULE" through CSS selector. .

Comment: I am working as an external tester. I can't request the development team to change the HTML code. Is it still possible to get the button through CSS selector ?

Comment: Are you sure this is correct HTML? I see that the button end tag is missing here and also the start tag of div is missing

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[attribute selector?](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Attribute_selectors)

```
ul#createDropdownUl>li[tabindex="9"]>button
```

or if you want the last one, you could use [:last-child](https://css-tricks.com/almanac/selectors/l/last-child/):

```
ul#createDropdownUl>li:last-child>button
```

Answer (score 0):

If you are sure about the tabindex, then you can use the [attribute selector](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/CSS/Attribute_selectors):

```
#createDropdownUl li[tabindex='9'] button {
    font-weight: bold /*Sample CSS*/
}
```

Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/GCu2D/1171/

Or, if you are sure about the number of `li` elements, you can also use:

```
#createDropdownUl li:nth-child(2) button{color:red;}
```

Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/GCu2D/1172/

Answer (score 0):

You can target an element by it's attribute in CSS:

```
#createDropdownUl li[tabindex="9"] button
```

Or use `nth-child(x)` selector:

```
#createDropdownUl li:nth-child(9) button
```

There is no other way in CSS, unless you give it an ID.

Answer (score -1):

In standard css this would be:

```
button button
```

But you have to be careful on other pages it can also select 3rd, 4th and so on.

That is to say, there is no ordinality in standard css - only classes and id's and their hierarchy level (parent/child) relationships, unlike xpath.

Comment: Are you suggesting that i should update my CSS selector to  "ul#createDropdownUl>li>button button""

Comment: It seems that your answer contains code. Please format it appropriately using the MarkDown syntax.